# Safely release dependency injected wcf client in .net core

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, .net-core

I want to use Microsoft's dependency injection in .Net Core (2.2) to inject and safely release WCF clients. I'm using the "WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool" in VS2019 to add WCF proxy classes to my solution. Using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection I can register the clients in the services collection, but I can't seem to find a way of hooking into a release lifecycle event (as can be done in various other IoC frameworks, e.g. Autofac), to add code for doing a safe release according to Microsoft's recommendations described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/use-close-abort-release-wcf-client-resources

Is there any way of doing something like that in the quite basic dependency injection functionality that comes with .Net Core framework? Or am I forced to use 3rd party IoC framework?

#### Pseudo code:

So basically I want to do something like this:

```
// Register the channel factory for the service. Make it
// Singleton since you don't need a new one each time.
services.AddSingleton(p => new ChannelFactory<IWcfService>(
    new BasicHttpBinding(),
    new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/WcfService")));

// Register the service interface using a lambda that creates
// a channel from the factory.
// TODO: need a way to handle proper disposal, e.g. like OnRelease().
services.AddTransient<IWcfService>(p => 
        p.GetService<ChannelFactory<IWcfService>>().CreateChannel())
    .OnRelease(CloseChannel); // <---This is what I would like to do

static void CloseChannel<T>(T channel)
{
    var disp = (ICommunicationObject) channel;
    try
    {
        if (disp.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            disp.Abort();
        else
            disp.Close();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        disp.Abort();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException)
    {
        disp.Abort();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        disp.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}
```

But I need a way to hook into the service release lifecycle event, e.g. something like .OnRelease() in Autofac, so I can do proper disposal.

Comment: What do you mean that you can’t find a way of hooking into a release lifecycle event? The appropriate lifecycle is “Scope”, alternatively, we could use “transient” lifetime. each call automatically creates and destroys an instance of the client proxy class.
Can't the instance lifecycle created through “Scoped” solve your problem?

Comment: The thing is that for "cleanup" I need to do more than just have Microsoft's DI call Dispose(). I need to run the code shown in the CloseChannel method to do proper disposal of WCF client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if you still need a response, but on my end to resolve this issue I implemented the dispose into the partial class.

Each time the wcf client is disposed the correct clean up is made:

```
  public partial class MyWcfClient : IDisposable
{
    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                if (State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    Close();
                }

                success = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!success)
                {
                    Abort();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although it is not what I ideally was looking for (because I need a partial class for each wcf client I have), I will consider it the solution, since I haven't seen other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this same problem, I've created a wrapper class that I register as an intermediate in the DI:

```cs
public class ChannelWrapper<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger<ChannelWrapper<T>> _logger;

    public T Channel { get; }

    public ChannelWrapper(ChannelFactory<T> factory, ILogger<ChannelWrapper<T>> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        Channel = factory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Channel is not ICommunicationObject communicationObject)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            if (communicationObject.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Aborting faulted channel");
                communicationObject.Abort();
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Closing channel");
                communicationObject.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Aborting timed out channel");
            communicationObject.Abort();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug(ex, "Aborting channel");
            communicationObject.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Aborting channel during exception");
            communicationObject.Abort();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And register as follows:

```cs
services.AddTransient(typeof(ChannelWrapper<>));
services.AddSingleton(new ChannelFactory<ISomeService>(binding, new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:1234/someservice")));
services.AddTransient<ISomeService>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<ChannelWrapper<ISomeService>>().Channel);
```